# Windows 8 and Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm helping someone write an autobiography and have been using Word.  The chapters have many pictures with captions and is in a 6 X 9 size.  Whenever I make any slight changes or go back to a chapter, EVERYTHING seems to have shifted and I start all over again.  I'm new to this, but this wonderful 85 year old gentleman wants this thing finished and I was wondering is there is perhaps a free program I can transfer the chapters I have been working on to without much difficulty and while he is still living and able to enjoy this?  I'm just helping because he is such a dear, but I'm terribly frustrated with redoing chapters 25 times!
Thank you so very much!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, Michelle. Unfortunately, you haven't explained if you want the pictures to stay in an absolute position & the text flow around them as you change it, or if you want the pictures to stay in the same position relative to the text as it changes. So both of the answers below are correct! You might want to add to your question what behavior you want to see with the pictures, as you edit, i.e. do you want them to stay fixed to a page, take up the full page, move with text etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the horizontal & vertical positioning of your elements to be Absolute relative to the Page. If you make them absolutely positioned relative to the Page then they shouldn't move even if you modify elements around it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the photo and choose in line with text in your formatting. Use the alignment of your text (center, left, right, justify) as to the image positioning.